# When I try to add string in the ouput, I get a syntax error

Tags: string, syntax

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


students=[lloyd,alice,tyler]

for student in students:
    print('name: %s' %s student['name'])
```

I get the following error:

```
print('Name: %s' %s student['name'])

                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My expected outcome is:

```
Name: Lloyd
Name: Alice
Name: Tyler
```

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Answer (score 0):

See the changes I have made in the for loop:

```js
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


students=[lloyd,alice,tyler]

for (student in students){
   console.log(students[student]['name'])
}
```